# How to get all stores collection include the store id 0 in magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, store-view, stores

I have tried to get all the stores in Magento 2.

```
$stores = $this->storeManager->getStores();
$ids= array();
foreach ($stores as $storeId => $storeData) {
    $ids[] = $storeId;
}

print_r($ids);
```

output returns `1`.

But in DB it has two store codes "admin" and "default":

[image: stores in DB]

How do I get both stores ids?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ids = array_keys($this->storeManager->getStores(true));
```

The first (optional) parameter makes the StoreManager include the default store (which has ID 0). Furthermore, the keys of the returned array will be the store IDs so you may get them quickly by using `array_keys()`.

Answer (score 12):

You can use a default Magento store repository `\Magento\Store\Api\StoreRepositoryInterface`. Add it as dependency and call the `getList` method.

```
/** @var \Magento\Store\Api\StoreRepositoryInterface $repository */
$stores = $repository->getList();
foreach ($stores as $store) {
    echo 'Store: ' . $store->getId();
    echo ' --- ';
}
```

will output all ids:

[image: output]